# Out of bounds of Array while trying to get value in it

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

Alright, so I have this exercise, where I am entering some kind of text, and as the second task, i need to find the longest sequence that exits in that text, sequence work like this:
*when the program finds the number, that's one word(and i just need the length of it)
In my program, it is found Write2 function, and the error occurs on line 43.
Here is the program, thanks for the help! !(This comment is a test input with which i am trying it: Xyz7jkl9ylk2XZjwasd)!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VeryHigh2
{
    //Xyz7jkl9ylk2XZjwasd
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string word = Console.ReadLine();
            int n = word.Length / 4;

            Console.WriteLine("             IZLAZI               \n-------------ODGOVOR 1-------------\n");
            Write1(word);
            Console.WriteLine("\n-------------ODGOVOR 1-------------\n");
            Write2(word,n);
        }
        static void Write2(string word,int n)
        {
            int[] Sequence = new int[n];
            string s = "";
            int i = 0;
            int counter = 1;
            while(i < Sequence.Length)
            {
                for (int t = 0; t < word.Length; t++)
                {
                    char c = word[t];
                    if (c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9')
                    {
                        counter++;
                        if (s == "")
                        { 
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int a = s.Length;
                            Sequence[i] = a;
                            s = "";
                            i++;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s = s + Convert.ToString(c);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                if (counter == word.Length)
                {
                    Sequence[i] = s.Length;
                    int b = Sequence.Length;
                    i = b;
                }
            }
            int max = Sequence[0];
            for(int j = 1; j < Sequence.Length; j++)
            {
                if(max < Sequence[j])
                {
                    max = Sequence[j];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(max);
        }
        static void Write1(string word)
        {
            int counter1 = 0;
            int counter2 = 0;
            string lower = word.ToLower();
            string upper = word.ToUpper();
            char l = lower[0];
            char u = upper[0];
            
            for(int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                if(l == word[i] || u == word[i])
                {
                    counter1++;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 1; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                l = lower[i];
                u = upper[i];
                for(int a = 0; a < word.Length; a++)
                {
                    if (word[a] == l || word[a] == u)
                    {
                        counter2++;
                    }
                }
                if(counter2 == counter1)
                {
                    goto counter;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tekst nije uravnotezen!");
                    break;
                }
                counter:
                counter2 = 0;
                if(i == word.Length - 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tekst je uravnotezen!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to fix the while loop, because I thought the problem was in it, but that's not the thing, I tried to assign the variable with the value i want to insert into array, because i thought it was some sort of bug, but nope, nothing worked...

Comment: You are manipulating `i` within the for loop, thus it might get greater that `Sequence.Length`

Comment: It is not clear to me what the actual goal is. Finding the longest consecutive sequence of numbers?

Comment: Thanks for the tip derpirscher, but that wasn't the case, the problem was that the counter never actually riched the number that is equal to word.Length, now it works! Thanks anyway!
And yes, JonasH, i was trying to find the longest sequence.